# CSS: Detecting IE in different standard modes?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

So I need to detect IE11 in IE7 standards mode and IE9 in IE7 standards mode, preferably thru CSS only.

I have no real control over the HTML or JavaScript. What I have complete control over is the CSS-file.

I'm open to any dirty trick/hack to send different styling to the two different browsers.

To be clear:

```
body{ 
background: red; /*Awesome IE11 hack here somewhere*/
background: green; /*Mindboggling IE9 hack around here*/
}
```

IE11 in IE7 standards mode should have a red background.
IE9 in IE7 standards mode should have a green background.

With a hack, I'm thinking in the line of something like this:
from http://browserhacks.com/

```
_::selection, .selector:not([attr*='']) {}
```

The above supports everything but IE8 and Firefox.

Pretty please, with sugar on top...

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. None of the other questions is asking for a CSS solution.

Comment: Not a duplicate. OP is asking if the hack can be in the CSS only file. The links you provided offer a solution if the OP can edit the HTML and add JS. But to answer the question, I don't think it's possible because you can't really detect the browser in the CSS file, you need to do that at page pre-process. However, it would be interesting if there was a way.

Comment: @jBoive I don't know if you have access to the server, but this might be a solution for you http://www.conditional-css.com/usage - then again if you had access to the server, you could probably edit the HTML or JS :)

Comment: @disinfor - No I know you can't detect the browser per say. I'm looking for a hack that only one browser supports and not the other, like: http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: +1 for the sugar ;) this does beg the questions: do ie11 and ie9 in ie7 mode behave differently? Why do you need to know - academic excersice or a boss asking you to?

Comment: @jBoive Yeah, I get what your asking. It almost is begging for a vendor prefix answer, but discerning between IE versions may not be possible in CSS alone.

Comment: @disinfor Sure you can. This for instance will only work on IE10+: _:-ms-input-placeholder, :root .selector {}

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve with this approach? Our goal (I work on the IE team) is to ensure that IE 7 document mode is the same in IE 9 or IE 11... if it wasn't, it would kind of defeat the purpose :)

Comment: I have "no" control over the HTML, as it's generated by the server. I'm trying to align a button with an input field. The same code (css, html, javascript) is used but it looks different, depending on the browser. In IE11 it's one pixel too big, compared to when it looks good in IE9. This is IE11 when IE9 looks good: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9681254/ie11ie7standardsmode.png

Comment: @jBoive that's awesome. I'm guessing you could get it to work with some serious dirty hacking :) Good luck!

Comment: @jBoive Are you *forcing* IE 7 Standards Mode onto your users via an `x-ua-compat` meta tag or header? If so, why?

Comment: @JonathanSampson - It's not me, it's IBM Connections. It's using a header: X-UA-Compatible:IE=EmulateIE7 But why we're doing it isn't really the issue here. IE11 & IE9 have differences in their IE7 Standards mode and I need to patch the differences with CSS.

Comment: @jBoive Can you create a reduced demo of the issue; something we can test locally? Further, if there is a layout difference for IE 7's document mode between IE 9 and IE 11, I would like to discuss it with the rest of the team.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - I can have a go. I'll post back once I have an example for you to look at. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In HTML:

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place content here to target all Internet Explorer users.
<![endif]-->
```

[In CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/evildonald/jLuF5/)

Comment: Please don't replace your answers. Add another answer instead.

Comment: And please add one that actually answers the question asked.

Comment: This won't work as IE10+ doesn't support conditional comments. I can't modify the HTML and I'm reluctant to add any more JS. As stated in the original question.